# Where is this structure in Berlin?

Tags: where-on-earth, berlin, architecture

What is the location of this structure in Berlin?

I know it was part of a test project for the 'Germania' plan, but I cant find any information for the exact location in Berlin.

[image: Berlin Structure]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [caption on this online version of the image at Getty Images](http://www.gettyimages.fr/detail/photo-d%27actualit%C3%A9/germany-berlin-tempelhof-load-testing-structure-at-photo-dactualit%C3%A9/548153951) says:

> Germany Berlin Tempelhof (Tempelhof-Schoeneberg) - load testing structure at General-Pape-Strass, built 1941 by Albert Speer, who wanted to test the load carrying capacity building ground for the planned triumphal arch of Hitler's GERMANIA project

[Google maps call it Schwerbelastungskörper and places it here](https://goo.gl/maps/wdY3dov5nj22) at

> General-Pape-Straße 34A, 12101 Berlin, Germany

The structure [has its own website](http://www.schwerbelastungskoerper.de/en/), and is open for visits. English speakers can find some information [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwerbelastungsk%C3%B6rper)

Comment: Thanks @JoErNanO
It goes by the name Schwerbelastungskörper (heavy load-bearing body)
Need to brush up on my German!

Comment: @davidb I was able to find the address with the english phrase "heavy load test structure", used several times in the Guardian article I presume you were reading.

Comment: Yes @CMaster This article? http://www.theguardian.com/cities/2016/apr/14/story-of-cities-hitler-germania-berlin-nazis
Fascinating stuff!

Comment: @davidb, I do not think that the name implies that it is the body that is bearing the load.

Answer (score 3):

[Here it is, on Street View.](https://goo.gl/maps/AzBbZMDkM6R2)

This structure is a [load-testing structure](http://www.gettyimages.com/pictures/germany-berlin-tempelhof-load-testing-structure-at-general-news-photo-548153951) planned to be part of Hitler's triumphal arch.